# dynamic view by date arguments in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm new to drupal, currently im stuck with this problem.

I want to create a article view ("tip of the day") wherein the content of the will automatically changed accordingly. The default value would be the current date.

For example:

**http://localhost/test**
this will get the current date as the default filter. If no items found it will give no results found.

when i go to **http://localhost/test/20111220** the view will automatically get the value of the date parameter in the url and output the content on that date.

How can I achieved this?

Any thoughts or ideas there?

Thank you.

Comment: You are using [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views)?

Comment: the view is part of a panel. and whenever the date is provided in the url it will display the contents of the view according to the date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Views then try the following.

1. Add ***Contextual filters*** in ***Advanced*** fieldset and select ***Date: Date (node)*** filter.
2. In it's settings in ***When the filter value is NOT in the URL*** fieldset tick ***Provide default value*** and leave ***Current date***
3. ***Add multiple value identifier*** set to ***No***
4. ***Dates to compare*** set to ***Only this field***
5. Between ***Date field(s)*** checkboxes select ***Content: Post date***
6. ***Method*** set to ***OR***

After that, by accessing your ***/test*** page you would have the last added content and by accessing ***/test/%date%*** you would have content for that date. For example ***/test/2011-12-23***

***%date%*** should be as ISO date/period format (i.e. YYYY, YYYY-MM, YYYY-MM-DD, YYYY-W99, YYYY-MM-DD--P3M, P90D, etc).

**EDITED: 19-01-2012**

Follow this path `http://yoursite/admin/structure/views/import` in your site and put the following data to code textfield:

```
$view = new view;
$view->name = 'test';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'test';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'test';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['query_comment'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'list';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['hide_empty'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['default_field_elements'] = 0;

/* No results behavior: Global: Text area */
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['id'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['field'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['label'] = 'No results';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['empty'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['content'] = 'No articles found.';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['format'] = 'full_html';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['tokenize'] = 0;

/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['alter_text'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['make_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['absolute'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['strip_tags'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['trim'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['html'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['hide_empty'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['empty_zero'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['link_to_node'] = 1;

/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';

/* Contextual filter: Date: Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['id'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['field'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['default_argument_skip_url'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['use_fromto'] = 'no';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['date_fields'] = array(
    'node.created' => 'node.created',
);

/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;


/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
    'page' => 'page',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'test';
```

Now by following to `/test` page you'll have date as today's date. You can also use your date type as `20120119`.

Comment: hi thank you for the reply. I have tried the above steps, however its not filtering. So even if I go to the date that has no data, it still returning contents. And is there a way to modify the date format?. because  it should be like this test/20111220. ? thanks.

Comment: Hello I tried again but i got this error. "Contextual filter handler node.date_argument is not available."

Comment: What you select in your view? Nodes? Can you give more details about it?

Comment: hello vlad thanks for ur prompt reply. It was my mistake I didn't enable the date views. Now the only problem left was to set an open ended range like <= 20120311 or >= 20120311... I dont see any option in the contextual filter to do that.