# Create a view using YYYY/MM/DD

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I have several content types (article, blog, event, etc) that I would like to have an archive view for.

For example, I would like to be able to view the blogs in these ways:

```
blogs/ (all blogs)
blogs/YYYY/ (blogs by year)
blogs/YYYY/MM (blogs by month)
blogs/YYYY/MM/DD (blogs by day)
blogs/YYYY/MM/DD/slug (specific entry)
```

I am using a custom *Date field* (not the node creation date) to create the *YYYY*, *MM* and *DD*.

I have searched and searched and can't find anything to help...

Comment: Maybe this would help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599219/dynamic-view-by-date-arguments-in-drupal-7/8614398#8614398

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer for what I'm trying to do. My main problem is needing the url to follow the YYYY/MM/DD format in the URL. I think there is something with arguments and selecting a date and then using PHP to break down the publication date of a node and compare it to the argument, but I just can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using Table Display and by Grouping your Post Date by Year, month and